# Opengl move only background items

Tags: android, opengl-es

i make simple interface in opengl (it's left right and just a press buttons)
i put them to bottom of screen

they maked by opengl( jsut a boxes from two triangles)

i want to move my screen to left or to right side. 
so in  onDraw method im using this code

```
 @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glOrthof(0, glWidth, glHeight, 0, 0, 1);
        // ==================================================================================================
        gameField.drawGameField(gl);
        drawInterface(gl);
     }
```

for draw object from interface or from gameField  im using this code

```
public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {      gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
           gl.glLoadIdentity();  
           gl.glTranslatef(0 , 0 , 0); //
           gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
           gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
           gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
           gl.glVertexPointer( 2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
           gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
           gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
           gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
     }
```

how i create items. Interface leftButton = new Interface();
than in onDrawFrame im just call  leftButton.draw(gl);

for background i made other class where im draw all objects from game(not interface)

simple code

```
public void drawGameField(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glTranslatef(moveWidth, moveHeight, -1);
        background.draw(gl);
        yama.draw(gl);
    }
```

**so what the problem**,  as we see in last function (drawGameField) i set gl.glTranslatef(moveWidth,moveHeight,-1);

in onDrawFrame i call this func and it's work perfect. My game screen moving left or right ( it's like a big 2d map which i want to scroll) but problem that  = my interface buttons move too to left or to right , and i cant understand how to fix this.  Maybe someone know how to fix this ?:( Please

**UPD**
if set glTranslatef before gameField.draw

```
gl.glTranslatef(moveWidth,moveHeight,0);
gameField.drawGameField(gl);
        drawInterface(gl);
```

than all on screen moving

if set after

```
gameField.drawGameField(gl);
gl.glTranslatef(moveWidth,moveHeight,0);
drawInterface(gl);
```

than translatef not working, also if i changed place ( first drawInterface than gameField) than translatef not working too (

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You didn't reset/update MODELVIEW matrix before drawing of UI. Try to call gl.glLoadIdentity(); before drawInterface(gl);